# Cypher: Personalized PageRank with multiple source nodes returning duplicates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a particular Cypher query that runs personalized PageRank over a set of source nodes. I want to `RETURN` the top `n` scoring nodes including their PageRank scores, additional properties, and all relationships between these nodes.

With the help of SO I've gotten to this point:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE p.paper_id IN $paper_ids
CALL algo.pageRank.stream(null, null, {direction: "BOTH", sourceNodes: [p]})
YIELD nodeId, score
WITH p, nodeId, score ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 25

MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = nodeId
WITH collect(nodeId) as ids, collect(n {.*, score}) as nodes
CALL apoc.algo.cover(ids) YIELD rel
RETURN ids, nodes, collect(rel) as rels
```

The only problem I'm having is that this query returns duplicate nodes. For example, a node can be returned several times with different PageRank scores. I suspect this is due to having multiple source nodes, so the different scores correspond to the PageRank scores for each source node. There are no duplicates when PageRank is run for a single source node.

This is an issue because I want to `RETURN` `n` *unique* nodes (in the above code block `n` = 25). In a typical run with two source nodes I get about 21-22 unique nodes.

How would I go about ensuring I `RETURN` `n` unique nodes?

Comment: So how do you want to resolve the different page ranks? Can you just take the `MAX(score)` as the final pageRank? The `RETURN DISTINCT` will remove duplicate rows, but if there are different values in the duplicate rows, you will need to add logic to resolve those differences to get the final distinct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tezra says, you need to determine how you want to resolve multiple `score`s for the same `p`.

The following options all involve making a simple change to this clause:

```
    WITH p, nodeId, score
```

Options:

- Use the maximum `score`:

  ```
  WITH p, nodeId, MAX(score) AS score
  ```
- Use the minimum `score`:

  ```
  WITH p, nodeId, MIN(score) AS score
  ```
- Use the average `score`:

  ```
  WITH p, nodeId, AVG(score) AS score
  ```